# Php Version issue in Drupal

Tags: php, installation, drupal-8

I have update php version from 7.1 to 7.4 .I have done the installation through following terminal command

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php7.4-common php7.4-mysql php7.4-xml php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-curl php7.4-gd php7.4-imagick php7.4-cli php7.4-dev php7.4-imap php7.4-mbstring php7.4-opcache php7.4-soap php7.4-zip php7.4-intl -y
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And when i check my php version

```
php -v
```

Got output like

```
PHP 7.4.6 (cli) (built: May 14 2020 10:02:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.6, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

> Your PHP installation is too old. Drupal requires at least PHP 7.3.0.
>   See the system requirements page for more information.
>   when i create a new page and check `phpversion();`,`version is 7.1`

Please Help.Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: You also need to tell your web server (Apache, NGINX, etc) to use the new version

Comment: @Phil thanks for the comment. please help me

Answer (score 2):

I got it now.After installation i did the following steps

```
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

butphpversion(); i got 7.1.

so did the following step

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
service apache2 restart
```

Now working.

Answer (score 1):

If **apache2**:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.4
sudo service apache2 restart
```

PHP version for a specific website can also be set through to the .htaccess file in the following way.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php74 .php
```

If **nginx**:

Take a backup of the default configuration file then change the FastCGI backend to use the new PHP-FPM socket, save and exit the file

```
location ~ \.php$ {;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}
```

Restart nginx:

```
sudo service nginx restart
```